# Generate a random point in a specific plane in C

Tags: c, algorithm

I have a 2D plane in three dimensions: *x*+*y*+*z*=1, and I want to generate random points(x,y,z) on the plane. How can I choose these points so that they are distributed uniformly?

Comment: Please remember that SO is not a *code writing service*, please show us what you've tried, we'll gladly sort out the problem. :)

Comment: Generate `x` and `y`, and then calculate `z`.

Comment: You need to be much more specific than that. What exactly are you having a problem with: designing an algorithm, C syntax, generating random numbers or something else? Reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask first won't hurt either.

Comment: What kind of distribution should the points have?

Comment: You can't generate random points without specifying the allowed range and distribution. What's a "3D plane"? A plane is 2-dimensional by definition. You mean a 2D plane in 3 dimensions.

Comment: This is a great question, sufficiently specified, and with a useful non-obvious answer. It should be voted up highly.

Comment: It's quite obvious that what he means is that he wants to choose a uniformly-distributed random point on the 3D surface x+y+z = 1.

Comment: Wait a minute...I take everything back. This surface extends infinitely, meaning you DO have to also specify the random range. Much more difficult than I thought at first.

Comment: I edited the question so that it is a bit more clear, but it doesn't answer the question raised by @LeeDanielCrocker: you cannot select uniformly distributed points from an infinite plane (or infinite line for that matter), so *you must specify some finite limits*.

Answer (score 6):

### The Problem

As mentioned in the comments, the question was under specified. Despite that it's a interesting question. Because no distribution was given I just picked one. Here is the more precise(?)/general(?) question I will answer:

> Suppose I have a plane `P` in `R^3` defined by `ax + by + cz = d`.
>
> Let `c` be in the point on `P` closest to the origin.
>
> How can I uniformly choose a point on `P` within some radius `r` of `c`?

### The Algorithm

Let `n = (a,b,c)`. `n` is the vector normal to `P`.

## direction

1. Generate any non-zero vector on the plane `ax + by + cz = d`, call it `w`. You can do this by taking the cross product of `n` with any non-zero vector not parallel to `n`.
2. Rotate `w` around `n` by a random angle in `[0,2pi)`. You can do this using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula.
3. so , now you got direction by normalizing it

```
direction = direction  /  direction.magnitude
```

## origin of the ray

1. If `d` is 0, we're done. Otherwise:
2. Calculate  c = distance of plane from  Vector3(0 , 0 , 0)
   according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_plane.
3. Translate Origin of ray

```
 origin of the ray = vector3.zero +  c * ( n )
```

scale = random.range(min , max)

#### So the point is

- origin_of_the_ray + scale * (direction_)

### The Code

Here is my C implementation of the algorithm. I wrote all the vector machinery from scratch so it's a little messy. I have not tested this throughly.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct {
    double x, y, z;
} vec3;

vec3 vec(double x, double y, double z);
vec3 crossp(vec3 u, vec3 v);
vec3 add(vec3 u, vec3 v);
double dotp(vec3 u, vec3 v);
double norm2(vec3 u);
double norm(vec3 u);
vec3 scale(vec3 u, double s);
vec3 normalize(vec3 u);
void print_vec3(vec3 u);

// generates a random point on the plane ax + by + cz = d
vec3 random_on_plane(double r, double a, double b, double c, double d) {
    // The normal vector for the plane
    vec3 n = vec(a, b, c);

    // create a normal vector on the plane ax + by + cz = 0
    // we take any vector not parallel to n
    // and find the cross product
    vec3 w;
    if (n.x == 0)
        w = crossp(n, vec(1,0,0));
    else
        w = crossp(n, vec(0,0,1));

    // rotate the vector around n by a random angle
    // using Rodrigues' rotation formula
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula
    double theta = ((double)rand() / RAND_MAX) * M_PI;
    vec3 k = normalize(n);
    w = add(scale(w, cos(theta)),
            scale(crossp(k, w), sin(theta)));

    // Scale the vector fill our disk.
    // If the radius is zero, generate unit vectors
    if (r == 0) {
        w = scale(w, r/norm(w));
    } else {
        double rand_r = ((double)rand() / RAND_MAX) * r;
        w = scale(w, rand_r/norm(w));
    }

    // now translate the vector from ax + by + cz = 0
    // to the plane ax + by + cz = d
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_plane
    if (d != 0) {
        vec3 t = scale(n, d / norm2(n));
        w = add(w, t);
    }

    return w;
}

int main(void) {
    int i;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        vec3 r = random_on_plane(10, 1, 1, 1, 1);
        printf("random v = ");
        print_vec3(r);
        printf("sum = %f, norm = %f\n", r.x + r.y + r.z, norm(r));
    }
}

vec3 vec(double x, double y, double z) {
    vec3 u;
    u.x = x;
    u.y = y;
    u.z = z;
    return u;
}

vec3 crossp(vec3 u, vec3 v) {
    vec3 w;
    w.x = (u.y * v.z) - (u.z * v.y);
    w.y = (u.z * v.x) - (u.x * v.z);
    w.z = (u.x * v.y) - (u.y * v.x);
    return w;
}

double dotp(vec3 u, vec3 v) {
    return (u.x * v.x) + (u.y * v.y) + (u.z * v.z);
}

double norm2(vec3 u) {
    return dotp(u, u);
}

double norm(vec3 u) {
    return sqrt(norm2(u));
}

vec3 scale(vec3 u, double s) {
    u.x *= s;
    u.y *= s;
    u.z *= s;
    return u;
}

vec3 add(vec3 u, vec3 v) {
    u.x += v.x;
    u.y += v.y;
    u.z += v.z;
    return u;
}

vec3 normalize(vec3 u) {
    return scale(u, 1/norm(u));
}

void print_vec3(vec3 u) {
    printf("%f %f %f\n", u.x, u.y, u.z);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Eugene had it almost right: generate two random numbers on the interval [0,1), call them A, B.  Then x = min(A,B), y = max(A,B) - x, z = 1 - (x + y).  Basically, you pick two points on the line [0,1) and your three coordinates are the three intervals defined by those two points.

Comment: P.S. This only applies if the range of x,y, and z is [0,1), which you don't say in your problem. This surface extends infinitely, so you have to be more specific about ranges.

Comment: ...and scale by `a`, `b` and `c`. But you always get points distributed within a triangle.

Answer (score 1):

I'll first give you a simple algorithm

```
x = rand()
y = rand()
z = 1 - x - y
```

Now lets see an implementation of that algorithm

This code will produce any sort of numbers ( +ve or -ve )

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int main()
  {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int x= ( rand() - rand() )  ;
    int y= ( rand() - rand() )  ;
    int z=1-x-y;
    printf("x=%d y=%d z=%d",x,y,z); 
  }
```

just use `srand()` to seed the random number generator, and use `rand()` to assign a random number.

If you need to create random numbers with a range, then use `rand() % ( maxnumber + 1 )` where maxnumber is the maximum value you want.

If you want all of your numbers to be positive, then try this

```
int main()
  {
    srand(time(NULL));  
    int x, y , z = -1;
    while ( z < 0 ) 
     {
      x = rand()  ;
      y = rand() ;
      z = 1 - (x + y );
     }
    printf("x=%d y=%d z=%d",x,y,z); 
  }
```

**WARNING**
the above code might take some time to execute, so don't expect an instant result

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker , it's supposed to be random numbers

Comment: Yes, but random numbers still have a distribution function. Generally one wants them uniformly distributed (that is, each set (x,y,z) is equally likely). Your scheme makes sets where x > z more likely.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker , I've edited. Although it may not be the best, it fixes that problem.

Comment: Won't that generate negative numbers?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker , I'll admit that I'm not good at math, but what's wrong with negative numbers ? The OP has not said anything about that, and as far as I remember, there can be negative points on a cartesian plane.

Comment: You're right, I assumed a positive range with no reason.